# How to get selected Item from listbox to context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contextmenu

So I know there are similar questions out there but I'm still confused and hope someone can help me. i had a listbox with the ability to select an item and it would add a property. I now have a context menu as the layout is exactly what I need but I'm struggling to make my click event work, currently I can't do anything with mine just now, but I have the code for the code behind on the list box to work, can someone help me with having the lsitbox click event work on the context menu please :)?

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBox = sender as ListBox;
        if (listBox.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var item = listBox.SelectedItems[0] as PropertyNode;
        viewModel.AddPropertyNode(item);
    }
```

**Edit**

Here is my XAML that I have with my context menu just now

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="AddNodeTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#F7F7F7">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <DrawingBrush Viewport="8,8,8,8" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#F7F7F7">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,50,50"/>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="ButtonAdd" Click="ButtonAdd_Click" Height="30" Width="130" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type syncfusion:Node}}}">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid Background="#F7F7F7">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image Source="Images/icon_plus.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Add Property" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="LightGray" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F7F7F7"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="_Copy Existing" Icon="{StaticResource ImageCopy}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableProperties}" Click="MenuItem_Click">
                                <MenuItem.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                        <Style.Resources>
                                            <Image x:Key="img" x:Shared="False" Width="12" Height="12" Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}" 
                                                   Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="ContentSource" Value="Icon">
                                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Style.Resources>
                                        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubMenuItem">
                                                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </MenuItem.Resources>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="Upscale well logs"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Upscale well_top attributes"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Upscale point attributes" Icon="{StaticResource ImagePointSet}">
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="Calculate"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Button.ContextMenu>
                </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**Code behind for context menu, I know it's not much but this is as far as I can get**

```
 private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    }
```

**Current output**

[image]

Comment: Did you add the click event to the context menu item? If you edit the context menu and double click on the menu item, it'll add the event handler and then you just put your code in there just like the list box.

Comment: currently does your code compile and run? There is a rule here that you cannot set the event handler in a Style scope unless you set the event on the element having that same Style.

Comment: Yeah my code does compile and run quite happily I'll show you what I currently have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling and asking around I found an answer and thought I post it for anyone who might have this problem also, just it's in the form of my problem, which should be easy enough to edit :)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddNodeTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#F7F7F7">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <DrawingBrush Viewport="8,8,8,8" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#F7F7F7">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,50,50"/>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="ButtonAdd" Click="ButtonAdd_Click" Height="30" Width="130" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type syncfusion:Node}}}">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid Background="#F7F7F7">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image Source="Images/icon_plus.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Add Property" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="LightGray" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F7F7F7"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy Exisiting" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableProperties}" Click="AddExistingProperty_OnClick" Icon="Images/Copy.bmp" FontFamily="MS Reference Sans Serif">
                                <MenuItem.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                        <Style.Resources>
                                            <Image x:Key="img" x:Shared="False" Width="10" Height="10" Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}" 
                                                   Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="ContentSource" Value="Icon">
                                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Style.Resources>
                                        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubMenuItem">
                                                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </MenuItem.Resources>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="Upscale well logs" Click="AddProperty_OnClick" Tag="UpscaleWellLogs" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}" Icon="Images/WellLogs.png" FontFamily="MS Reference Sans Serif"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Upscale well top attributes" Click="AddProperty_OnClick" Tag="UpscaleWellTopAttributes" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}" Icon="Images/WellTop.png" FontFamily="MS Reference Sans Serif"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Upscale point attributes" Click="AddProperty_OnClick" Tag="UpscalePointAttributes" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}" Icon="Images/PointSet.png" FontFamily="MS Reference Sans Serif"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Calculate" Click="AddProperty_OnClick" Tag="Calculate" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}" Icon="Images/calculator.png" FontFamily="MS Reference Sans Serif"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Button.ContextMenu>
                </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

private void AddExistingProperty_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
        var item = menuItem.DataContext as PropertyNode;
        viewModel.AddPropertyNode(item);
    }

    private void AddProperty_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MenuItemActivated != null)
        {
            var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
            var command = menuItem.Tag as CognitiveTreeMenuCommand?;
            if (command.HasValue)
            {
                MenuItemActivated(this, new MenuItemEventHandlerArgs() { Command = command.Value });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you've correctly linked your code in the XAML. Something like:

```
<ListView SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
```

I note that we don't see any of your wpf xaml code. If this doesn't answer your question then it might help to add a glimpse of your xaml so we can identify why your Selector_OnSelectionChanged isn't being processed.

Thanks!